# HOW TO Change # of products per row, specific for each page layout

Tags: magento-1.7

[Display more items per row in products/category pages](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/display-more-items-per-row-in-products-page)

^ **This post is a guide to set 4 products per row | For all pages.**

I want to set a different amount of products for each page layout.

**THE GOAL:**

- **3 Products per row for 3 Column-Page Layout**
- **4 Products per row for 2 Column ^**
- **5 Products per row for 1 Column ^**

Please provide instructions to customize products per row.

Thank you

Comment: Hi statis-online and welcome to MageOverflow. What have you tried? What is the problem? This post should answer your question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/12901/217

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. The problem is I have some pages with space for only 3 products per row, and some with room for 5!||||| The 4 products per row edit doesn't change those pages to the desired # of products per row

Answer (score 1):

You can do these steps

1. Visit and edit this file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml
2. Find this

   `<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend">
        <layout>empty</layout>
        <count>6</count>
    </action>`
3. Before each of them add this code

   `<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>`
   As you see we change the number of product per row is 4 that 's mean we have to change to the number of product per page to the number what we can be divided 4. We choose 12 then do this

Go into admin and choose System->Configuration. Then on the left goto Catalog->Catalog. The page should now show the Grid only for ‘List Mode‘. For this example I choose to place in 12,24,36 for ‘Page on Grid Allowed Values‘ and 12 for ‘Products per Page on Grid Default Value‘.

[image]

Ok, get back to check if it work. Other than that, you can do the same for app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml

Comment: Hi, I need to customize each page layout with a different amount of products per line. The solution you provided is the same as the post I read before, it does not customize each page for 3 products per page, 4, and 5 depending on page layout.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

change page layout from local.xml file as per requirement use this code. I am using for catalog_category_layered handler . where i need 3 products in single row having 2-columns-left page layout.
  

    
    
            page/2columns-left.phtml
    
    
        3